# DatagridView 3rd level Nested Binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I'm using `Entity framework 6` and I'm developing with `DBFirst`.

In the database I have the following structure

```
Table : product category -> ProductCategory(ProductCategoryID, Name ...)
Table : product          -> Product ( ProductID, ProductCategoryID , ...)
Table : products in      -> ShelfProducts(ShelfID, ProductID, ... )
        stock location
```

In my Model I have...

```
class ShelfProduct
{
   ...
   ShelfID {set;get;}
   ProductID {set;get;}
   Quantity {set;get;}
   ...
}
class Product
{
   ...
   string Name {set;get;}
   virtual ProductCategory {set;get;}
}
class ProductCategory
{
   ....
   Name {set;get;}
}
```

I'm binding the `ShelfProduct` in my `datagridview` and I'm getting the properties `ShelfID`, `ProductID`, `Quantity`. Also I can show Product's Name using additional binding source with `DisplayMember`,`ValueMember` properties as 2nd level binding. But When I try to show in `datagridview` the `ProductCategory.Name` I can't do it.

I found a solution but has poor performance.

My solution is to add directly in the Model, int the class ShelfProduct a getter property like this

```
class ShelfProduct
{
   ...
   ShelfID {set;get;}
   ProductID {set;get;}
   Quantity {set;get;}
   ...
   CategoryName
   {
       get
       {
          using(DBContext db = new DBContext)
          {
              ProductCategory pc = db.ProductCategories.Find(this.Product.ProductCategory.ProductCateogryID);
              return pc.Name;
          }
       }
}
```

But the performance increasing dramatically. Also I can't use int he getter directly return `this.Product.ProductCategory.Name`  `ObjectDisposed` exception occurs.

How can I do it? Any solutions?

Comment: There are multiple ways for loading related entities in EF, I would definitely avoid the one you're doing. Have a look at tutorials on how to load related entities, use lazy loading and experiment on those. 
In your code, you are basically doing a round trip to the database for every product category you are going to display (one by one).

Comment: Etienne I can bind 2nd level related entities. But I can;t 3rd level. I searched on so , on google but all tutorials are things which I know.

Comment: have you tried to use Include method ?

Comment: Etienne I solved the problem yesterday. Using the Include method and using getter in the Model. Now also the performance is very good without lazy loading.

Comment: @Etienne when I use the Include method can I bind directly in the datagridview related properties such as Product.ProductCategory.Name in the DataPropertyName.

Comment: I believe so yes, have a look at this please: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: @Etienne I finded the solution yesterday. Thank you